# uncaughtSyntaxError/unexpected number error when i attempt to copy a php variable into a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, php, datetime

I have a program where in need to get todays date in php and then copy that variable to a javascript variable.  When i do i get an error uncaughtSyntaxError/unexpected number.  I use the date() function that should already store the date time as a string, i don't quite understand the reason for this error, any help is appreciated...my code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>

var tmr;// timer
var incidentReloader;
function UpdateTable()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    var tokens = xmlhttp.responseText.split("|");

        alert(tokens[0]+",    "+tokens[1]);
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","update_ajax_test.php?date1="+newDate,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
 </head>
<body onload="tmr=setInterval(UpdateTable,5000)">

<?php
mysql_connect("xxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx") or die("not logged in");
//////now selecting our database
mysql_select_db("xxxxxxxxxxxxxx") or die(mysql_error());

 $res = mysql_query("SELECT num FROM ajax_table");

$numEnter=$_GET['name'];
echo $numEnter;

echo'<form method="get" action="ajax_test.php">';
 echo'  <input type="text" name="name"><br>';
 echo' <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form"><br>';
 echo'</form>';

date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
```

$date is variable that i will have to copy into php

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
 echo $date;

mysql_query("INSERT INTO ajax_table(num,last_updated) VALUES ('$numEnter','$date')");



echo"<table border=1 id='t1'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{

    echo"<tr><td>";
    echo $row['num'];
    echo"</td></tr>";
}

echo"</table>";




?>

 <script type="text/javascript">
```

here is where i get the error

```
 var  newDate=<? echo $date; ?>;

 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Just do `var newDate = <?= time(); ?>;` and you have a unix timestamp instead, which seems more useful then the string you're using for database lookup ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
var newDate = "<?php echo $date ?>";
```

Comment: And cross your fingers that no one runs your code in a locale where " is a valid date character. **NO. DO IT PROPERLY THE FIRST TIME.**

Comment: I myself not 100% sure, but when ever you want to echo some php variable, you have enclose them in double quotes to make them a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
var newDate=<? echo json_encode($date); ?>;
```

Comment: but why json encode it ? If you json encode, it will still produce the string the same way like mine. It will be helpful for me also if you can elaborate ?

Comment: `var foo = "<?php $foo = '"'; echo $foo; ?>";`